# Protractor multiCapabilities on single browser

Tags: protractor

I am trying to write a single Protractor config file to test a website on desktop/laptop, Android, and iPhone cases.

The following works:

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: process.env.JHI_E2E_HEADLESS
        ? ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600']
        : ['--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600'],
    },
  },
```

The following also works:

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: process.env.JHI_E2E_HEADLESS
      ? ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600']
      : ['--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600'],
      mobileEmulation: {
        deviceName: 'iPhone 6/7/8 Plus'
      },
    },
  },
```

However, the following fails with the error

```
[chrome #01] [16:06:44] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[chrome #01] [16:06:45] I/runnerCli - Unexpected token {
```

```
  multiCapabilities: [
      {
        name: 'ChromeDesktop',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          args: process.env.JHI_E2E_HEADLESS
            ? ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600']
            : ['--disable-gpu', '--window-size=800,600'],
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'ChromeAndroid',
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
          args: process.env.JHI_E2E_HEADLESS
            ? ['--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=360,640']
            : ['--disable-gpu', '--window-size=360,640'],
          mobileEmulation: {
                deviceName: 'Galaxy S5'
            },
        },
      },
  ],
```

Can anyone kindly explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: hey, what does your error says after `unexpected token`

Comment: As @SergeyPleshakov has said, please post the full error message. I tried your multicapabilities setting and it doesn't return an error.

Comment: Hi, here's the full error: `[16:06:45] I/testLogger - [chrome #01] PID: 1556658
[chrome #01] Specs: /home/timl/Development/BIDS/src/test/javascript/e2e/features/send_bank_account.feature
[chrome #01] 
[chrome #01] [16:06:44] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[chrome #01] [16:06:45] I/runnerCli - Unexpected token {

[16:06:45] I/testLogger - 

[16:06:45] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[16:06:45] I/launcher - 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:06:45] I/testLogger - `

Comment: There's also this:
`[09:28:08] I/testLogger - 

[09:28:08] E/launcher - Runner process exited unexpectedly with error code: 1
[09:28:08] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:28:08] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed with exit code: 1
[09:28:08] I/launcher - chrome #11 failed with exit code: 1
[09:28:08] I/launcher - overall: 2 process(es) failed to complete
[09:28:08] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100`

Answer (score 0):

Adding below in protractor conf should work -

```
onPrepare: function () { require('ts-node').register({ project: 'e2e' }); }
```

[Link To Related GitHub Issue with Accepted Solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/975) -> It has the details why onPrepare should be used instead of default beforeLaunch for enabling multiple capabilities for browsers.